# flutter ：Why doesn't `Matrix4.rotationY` rotate along the Y axis?

Tags: flutter

The previous version of flutter was rotated along the middle of the Y axis, but now it is rotated along the left side, I want to know how to achieve the middle rotation.

flutter version:2.0.5

```dart
    _rotateController = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), vsync: this);
    _rotateAnimation = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController)




Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.rotationY(_rotateAnimation.value * 2 * pi),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  _rotateAnimation.value == 0
                      ? _rotateController.forward()
                      : _rotateController.reverse();
                },
                child:  Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.green, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        width: 50,
                        height: 100,
                        child: Text('aaa${_rotateAnimation.value}'),
                      )
                     
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer is :

```
 alignment: Alignment.center,
```

like this:

```dart
Transform(
 transform: Matrix4.rotationY(_rotateAnimation.value * 2 * pi),
 alignment: Alignment.center,
 child:...
```